# Why does cocoa use delegates rather than inheritance?

Tags: cocoa, inheritance, delegates

Why does cocoa use delegates rather than inheritance?

Comment: I don't know enough about obj-/cocoa to answer this question in debt (surely great answers will follow) but iirc the main argument is that using delegates allows for 'looser' coupling then using (multiple) inheritance (impossible in obj-c).

Comment: What is iirc? I haven't heard of it.

Comment: that is a perfect answer ChristopheD, you should post it as such

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With delegates, you can have one object be the delegate of many other objects. For example, you can have your MyController instance be the delegate of an NSTableView, an NSTextField, an NSWindow, and any other objects that compose your interface. This gives a compact place to put all of your user interface code related to one section of your UI.

If you'd done that with subclassing, you'd have to create one subclass every object you wanted callbacks from.

Also, this is a classic [inheritance vs composition](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UseCompositionAndInterfacesWithoutClassInheritance) question

Comment: I suppose this really is just the inheritance vs composition problem

Comment: Good point about writing one controller for multiple objects in your interface

Answer (score 5):

In general creating a subclass can be a time consuming process, requiring a lot of groundwork, and overriding various template methods.

Meanwhile, using a delegate allows you to create a simple object that answers a few specific question or reacts in various ways.

Now when you combine this with the dynamism that you can achieve by swapping out delegates on the fly it can create a very flexible robust system that promotes more code reuse.

There is some general discussions regarding these things [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_pattern) and [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delegation_(programming)).   You can also find some older SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49002/prefer-composition-over-inheritance) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832536/when-to-use-delegation-instead-of-inheritance).

Comment: How does a template take less effort to create than a subclass? On the other hand, the ability to swap out on the fly could be useful in some circumstances, but I don't see why it is necessary for Cocoa.

Comment: I'm not even so much sure that it's less work, but fewer levels of inheritence leads to a generally simpler design.  Simplicity is a Good Thing (tm).

Comment: As to Necessity.  Nothing is absolutely necessary, it was the opinion of the framework designers that given the constraints of the language that composition via delegation was the best design choice they could make.  After working in it for around a year I'm inclined to agree that there choice was a good one.  But it was a little odd for me when I first came to Cocoa from other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Discussed at length here:
http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?ExtendsIsEvil

And Java guys know this too:
http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-08-2003/jw-0801-toolbox.html

Comment: Might as well put a comment if you're not going to elaborate. What happens if these links become dead, like the first one?

Comment: Delegates simplify the customization of object behavior while minimizing coupling between classes. Inheritance is defined at compile time, delegation is not restricted like that and can be done at runtime.