# Using an interface to ensure every class has the same property

Tags: .net, vb.net, oop, inheritance, interface

I have a property on a page that gets a query-string value, I need this to be on all related pages. The pages already inherit a base class, and I don't want the property here as not everything that inherits this base class needs this particular property.

My idea was to create an interface with this property and have every page that needs the property implement this interface.

Is this good practice, or should I inherit the base class into another class with just this property and then have all pages inherit this instead of the base?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the implementation of the property will be the same on all pages that need them?
If you use an interface, all pages need to implement this, which will lead to a lot of copy/paste code.
Isn't it better to write some kind of provider class to which you can pass your page instance (if needed) and use this class to fetch the property?
You better use composition over inheritance here I think, because if you create another base class you will extend your page hierarchy with yet another base class.

Comment: I think you're right, to be honest Ive inherited (no pun intended) a bit of a mess. I need to spend some time looking at exactly what these pages are doing before I think of re-factoring. Ill vote this as this is the way I will go when ready

Answer (score 0):

I would say it does not matter much, but i prefer another inheritance level because you only have to write the code once. With the Interface you are more flexible, maybe you want in some cases no Auto Property but a check for null or something like that.

So if it is always the same Property then go with a inherited second base class, if you have different checks in the getter or setter then go with the interface.

Comment: Thanks,  the downside of the interface IS I have to write the implementation every time, but it also forces these pages to use the property. (as long as I remember to implement the interface!)

Answer (score 0):

Interfaces do not require you to duplicate the code! You can use delegation. This is similar to the accepted answer except in one way. An interface can be used to expose a contract to other classes that allow them to interact with your class in a consistent and powerful way. A key question then becomes, will external code ever want to "know" whether you Form has that functionality?

[delegation-instead-of-inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/832536/when-to-use-delegation-instead-of-inheritance)